# Applying Bootstrap css in MVC view

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap css

view :

```
    <div class="container">
    @using (Html.BeginForm(new { @class="form-horizontal"}))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)



   <div class="form-group">
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rank_name, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2" })
    <div class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Rank_name, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rank_name)
    </div>
  </div>

   <div class="form-group">
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.rank_code, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2" })
    <div class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.rank_code, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.rank_code)
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Target_amount, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2" })
    <div class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Target_amount, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Target_amount)
    </div>
  </div>
        <div class="form-group">        
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />

          </div>
        </div>


}
    </div>
```

but I'm not getting the output exactly what i want, 
[image]

I have used this  format 
[Horizontal form](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_form-horizontal&stacked=h)

but there is no space between those boxes and the box size is too long .I mean its not good format .what should i do?

Edited:
and my Layout :

```
 <head>
 @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

        <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 </head>
```

Edited 2:

I have put bootstap.css before the cite.css  then i got space between those boxes and box sizes are within that div tag 
but the entire page font size is very very small .I can't read those text.

Comment: Which version of Bootstrap are you using? If it's version 2: you're using a version 3 example. If it's version 3: Can you please post the resulting html? It's easier to first analyse if the html is correct and if not perhaps analyse if the asp.net mvc code is correct

Comment: @ckuijjer [this one v3.3.1](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

Comment: Damn, my initial idea was that the code looks good

Comment: @ckuijjer I hope the Code is Correct .

Comment: @ckuijjer I have Cite.css in my Layout form so is that make any crossing ?

Comment: Could be the case. I would suggest you to make the problem as small as possible. Remove all other css and perhaps even try it with the static html example you used. That might give a clue to what exactly goes wrong

Comment: in developer console check which css rules applying over bootstrap properties?

Comment: @aleha  i have firebug but i don't know how to check what you meant

Comment: @ckuijjer I removed that css but nothing different

Comment: Right click on the page in Firefox, do View Page Source, and copy & paste everything into the question. Perhaps that might help someone find the issue.

Comment: Have you tried `col-md-10`? I'm not 100% sure, but its usually dependant on screen size, and it looks like your testing on a desktop.

Comment: Are you sure you're using bootstrap template? Based on the screen shot, looks like it's the Internet Application template for asp.net mvc4 and you added the bootstrap js & css so the css might be conflicted between the bootstrap css and the default css.

Comment: @ekad I have checked by Removing cite.css but the Same result I got

Comment: What if you remove `@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")` from the layout?

Comment: @ekad I did that but the Same Result I got  without  bgcolor,header,etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your using bootstrap, you should use it like this:

**Don't use form-horizontal class in @using (Html.BeginForm(new {}))**

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rank_name, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2" })
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Rank_name, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rank_name)
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.rank_code, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2" })
        <div class="col-sm-7">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.rank_code, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.rank_code)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow nice that this has been answered. @swapnilnax can you explain why you can't use new `@using (Html.BeginForm(new { @class = ... }`. Is it a wrong overload?

Comment: @ckuijjer **form-horizontal** class contain aliginment properties like this: `.form-horizontal .control-label,
.form-horizontal .radio,
.form-horizontal .checkbox,
.form-horizontal .radio-inline,
.form-horizontal .checkbox-inline {
    padding-top: 7px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.form-horizontal .radio,
.form-horizontal .checkbox {
    min-height: 27px;
}

.form-horizontal .form-group {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}` so it apply the class for the form in (Html.BeginForm(new { @class = ... }

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the **class to col-sm-6** or to  **class to col-sm-4** depending on what you are looking for.This should reduce the length of the textbox.

And for the spacing between textbox add an id to the form-group and add a margin-bottom to that id .

So the complete code looks like

```
<div class=<div class="form-group" id="format_margin">        
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-6" >
          <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Enter email">

      </div>
    </div>
```

**And to the css file apply**

```
#format_margin{
        margin-bottom:10px;
       }
```

Comment: did you see this :http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_form-horizontal&stacked=h this is the code i exactly used but the result is not same

Comment: The class used is col-sm-10. Thus the length of the textbox is large.

Comment: if you want a smaller textbox use col-sm-6 or col-sm-4

Answer (score 0):

For showing the from control to your desired size on desired screen  you need to understand [bootstrap grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) system. The Bootstrap grid appropriately scales up to 12 columns as the device or viewport size increases. by assigning `col-sm-10` class you are assigning 10 column out of 12.For  smaller form controls you have to assign smaller value like `col-sm-5` or `col-sm-6`. You can customize the size is medium and large screen by applying col-md-5 and col-lg-4.
You can change the form like this in your view:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      </head>

      <body>
         <div class="container">
    @using (Html.BeginForm(new { @class="form-horizontal"}))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)



   <div class="form-group">
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Rank_name, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2" })
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Rank_name, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Rank_name)
    </div>
  </div>

   <div class="form-group">
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.rank_code, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2" })
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.rank_code, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.rank_code)
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Target_amount, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-2" })
    <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5 col-lg-5">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Target_amount, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Target_amount)
    </div>
  </div>
        <div class="form-group">        
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />

          </div>
        </div>


}
    </div>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      </body>

    </html>
```